# Does removing all data from a Sencha store also remove associated data?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a store and a model with a hasMany association.

If I call `Ext.getStore('SessionStore').removeAll()` does it also remove any associated data with the records in the store?

If not, how would I do this?

Comment: What do you want to say with "associate data"?

Answer (score 0):

if you console log a record in SessionStore you should have a property with the name of the association plus the suffix Store

e.g. if the name of the association is personalInformation there should be a new property in the record called personalInformationStore.

So the answer would be yes by removing a record or all from a store the associated data will also be removed as this data is part of the parent object.

Perhaps Ext.StoreManager.getCount() can help validate the existence of the data / objects.

I also recommend this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-inspector-for-sencha/pbeapidedgdpniokbedbfbaacglkceae?hl=en